# Lenovo s145 wi-fi drivers

Tags: drivers, 18.04, wireless, kernel, lenovo

(new Ubuntu user)

I am using a Lenovo S145 laptop and would like to use Ubuntu.

After installation (18.04 LTS, 5.3 kernel), wifi is not recognized, and I get a "No Wi-Fi Adapter Found" in settings.

I tried to follow different solutions such as https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new but I can't figure out which driver I should be using, or if anything I do actually affects anything.

Some additional iformation:

`lsusb`: `Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:c02f Realtek Semiconductor Corp.`

`lspci`: `01:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device c82f`

`uname -rs`: `Linux 5.3.0-050300-generic`

`lshw -C network`:

```
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Network controller
       product: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:4000(size=256) memory:94000000-9400ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 3
       logical name: enp0s20f0u1
       serial: 8e:42:45:d6:9d:9d
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.42.94 link=yes multicast=yes
```

(I guess the Ethernet interface is the USB tethering from my Android device)

`inxi -Fxz`:

```
System:    Host: Pumbaa Kernel: 5.3.0-050300-generic x86_64 bits: 64 gcc: 9.2.1
           Desktop: Gnome 3.28.4 (Gtk 3.22.30-1ubuntu4) Distro: Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Machine:   Device: laptop System: LENOVO product: 81W6 v: Lenovo IdeaPad S145-14IIL serial: N/A
           Mobo: LENOVO model: LNVNB161216 v: NO DPK serial: N/A UEFI: LENOVO v: DKCN24WW date: 11/26/2019
Battery    BAT0: charge: 36.5 Wh 99.9% condition: 36.5/35.0 Wh (104%) model: SMP L16M2PB2 status: Full
CPU:       Dual core Intel Core i3-1005G1 (-MT-MCP-) arch: N/A cache: 4096 KB
           flags: (lm nx sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx) bmips: 4761
           clock speeds: max: 3400 MHz 1: 974 MHz 2: 845 MHz 3: 959 MHz 4: 869 MHz
Graphics:  Card: Intel Device 8a56 bus-ID: 00:02.0
           Display Server: wayland (X.Org 1.19.6 ) driver: i915 Resolution: 1920x1080@59.96hz
           OpenGL: renderer: Mesa DRI Intel UHD Graphics (Ice Lake 4x8 GT1)
           version: 4.5 Mesa 19.2.8 Direct Render: Yes
Audio:     Card Intel Device 34c8 driver: snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 00:1f.3 Sound: ALSA v: k5.3.0-050300-generic
Network:   Card: Realtek Device c82f port: 4000 bus-ID: 01:00.0
           IF: N/A state: N/A speed: N/A duplex: N/A mac: N/A
Drives:    HDD Total Size: 256.1GB (3.4% used)
           ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 model: WDC_PC_SN520_SDAPMUW size: 256.1GB
Partition: ID-1: / size: 234G used: 8.2G (4%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/nvme0n1p2
RAID:      No RAID devices: /proc/mdstat, md_mod kernel module present
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 39.0C mobo: N/A
           Fan Speeds (in rpm): cpu: N/A
Info:      Processes: 234 Uptime: 1:04 Memory: 1729.7/7758.5MB Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Gcc sys: 7.4.0
           Client: Shell (bash 4.4.201) inxi: 2.3.56
```

Answer (score 2):

The rtlwifi-new may be able to support this, in terminal do

```
cd rtlwifi_new
git checkout rtw88
sed -i 's/0xC822/0xC82F/' pci.c
make
sudo make install
```

Reboot

Secure Boot must be disabled

In terminal run `wget -N -t 5 -T 10 https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info/raw/master/wireless-info && chmod +x wireless-info && ./wireless-info`

`cat wireless-info.txt | nc termbin.com`
Post URL in comments

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I tried out your method and it ran without errors - however I still get the same message under wifi settings.

Comment: netcat didn't work, but I copied the file to pastebin - hope it's enough: https://pastebin.com/Gf25wxkF

Comment: Uninstall the iwlwifi backports and reboot

Comment: Done, thank you. I can now see the list of networks, however it denies access from any of them, claiming incorrect passcode (I also created a hotspot to test that I'm not getting the passcode wrong...)

Comment: Run the script again and post a link to new results

Comment: https://pastebin.com/D2yccz6w

Comment: Access the router settings, move it to channel 6, go into encryption settings and put it on WPA2 only, no WEP/TKIP.  In terminal do `sudo sed -i 's/wifi.powersave = 3/wifi.powersave = 2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf`  reboot

Comment: I ran the command (still didn't fix the problem), however the router is a managed one and I can't change its settings... Is there another way around that point?

Comment: You could check the password, do `sudo cat /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/poran.nmconnection` see if it is correct

Comment: Yep, I see:
[wifi-security]
auth-alg=open
key-mgmt=wpa-psk
psk=
And then the correct password.

Comment: out of ideas now