# 18.04: No visible wireless networks Realtek 8822CE

Tags: networking, 18.04, drivers, realtek-wireless

**Outline**

I have a problem with a new computer where there are no visible wireless networks in the network settings and I am unable to connect to them. The computer is a Lenovo v14-IIL with a Realtek device c82f, the Realtek 8822CE.

---

**Done so far**

When booting Ubuntu 18.04 to this computer it first did not show any possibility to even connect to a wireless network. I used the answer from this thread: [Wifi adapter not found in ubuntu 18.04; no drivers for device rtl8822ce](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1216699/wifi-adapter-not-found-in-ubuntu-18-04-no-drivers-for-device-rtl8822ce), and it helped with enabling the wireless network card to be visible. But now the problem still persists in that I can't connect to any wifi.

When trying to select a network it just says "No Networks". I've gone through other thread to try and find the answer. So far I've run these commands and gotten this:

`lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3`

```
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:c82f]
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:c02f]
    Kernel driver in use: rtw_pci
    Kernel modules: rtwpci
```

`rfkill list all`

```
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
2: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

`sudo lshw -C network`

```
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: wlp1s0
       version: 00
       serial: 28:39:26:c4:51:39
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtw_pci driverversion=5.7.0-rc3+ firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:137 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:94000000-9400ffff
```

`dmesg | grep -i rtw_pci`

```
[   25.398709] rtw_pci 0000:01:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0003)
[   25.407821] rtw_pci 0000:01:00.0: Firmware version 7.3.0, H2C version 14
[   25.408830] rtw_pci 0000:01:00.0: Firmware version 7.3.0, H2C version 14
[   25.533550] rtw_pci 0000:01:00.0 wlp1s0: renamed from wlan0
[   26.793496] rtw_pci 0000:01:00.0: start vif 28:39:26:c4:51:39 on port 0
```

Fist the firmware did not work so I updated it to the latest version and now it doesn't give any errors and shows this.

`inxi -Fxz`

```
System:    Host: usrname-Lenovo-V14-IIL Kernel: 5.7.0-rc3+ x86_64
           bits: 64 gcc: 7.5.0
           Desktop: Gnome 3.28.4 (Gtk 3.22.30-1ubuntu4)
           Distro: Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Machine:   Device: laptop System: LENOVO product: 82C4 v: Lenovo V14-IIL serial: N/A
           Mobo: LENOVO model: LNVNB161216 v: SDK0J40697 WIN serial: N/A
           UEFI: LENOVO v: DKCN24WW date: 11/26/2019
Battery    BAT0: charge: 35.8 Wh 100.1% condition: 35.8/35.0 Wh (102%)
           model: SMP L16M2PB2 status: Full
CPU:       Quad core Intel Core i5-1035G1 (-MT-MCP-) 
           arch: N/A cache: 6144 KB
           flags: (lm nx sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx) bmips: 9523
           clock speeds: max: 3600 MHz 1: 1105 MHz 2: 1230 MHz 3: 760 MHz
           4: 1269 MHz 5: 1169 MHz 6: 811 MHz 7: 667 MHz 8: 1226 MHz
Graphics:  Card: Intel Device 8a56 bus-ID: 00:02.0
           Display Server: x11 (X.Org 1.20.5 )
           drivers: (unloaded: modesetting,fbdev,vesa)
           Resolution: 1920x1080@60.01hz
           OpenGL: renderer: Mesa DRI Intel UHD Graphics (Ice Lake 4x8 GT1)
           version: 4.5 Mesa 19.2.8 Direct Render: Yes
Audio:     Card Intel Device 34c8 driver: snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 00:1f.3
           Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture v: k5.7.0-rc3+
Network:   Card: Realtek Device c82f
           driver: rtw_pci port: 4000 bus-ID: 01:00.0
           IF: wlp1s0 state: down mac: <filter>
Drives:    HDD Total Size: 256.1GB (14.3% used)
           ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 model: WDC_PC_SN520_SDAPMUW size: 256.1GB
Partition: ID-1: / size: 234G used: 35G (16%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/nvme0n1p2
RAID:      No RAID devices: /proc/mdstat, md_mod kernel module present
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 41.0C mobo: N/A
           Fan Speeds (in rpm): cpu: N/A
Info:      Processes: 301 Uptime: 27 min Memory: 1593.9/7757.2MB
           Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Gcc sys: 7.5.0
           Client: Shell (bash 4.4.201) inxi: 2.3.56
```

`ip link show`

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: wlp1s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 28:39:26:c4:51:39 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: enp0s20f0u2c4i2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 6e:8d:c1:0e:5c:5c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

`iwconfig`

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

wlp1s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on

enp0s20f0u2c4i2  no wireless extensions.
```

`sudo iwlist wlp1s0 scanning`

This commands shows all the visible wifi's around so the wireless can find them.

`sudo gedit /etc/network/interfaces`

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

In this file I added the text below to use the network card since I found it on some threads, is it wrong?

```
auto wlp1s0
iface wlp1s0 inet dhcp
```

`lsmod`

```
rtwpci                 24576  0
```

This is the module the network card should use but I assume since it isn't connected to a wifi the module is not used (this module itself uses another module though, rtw88)

**Problem right now**

Right now I don't see what I need to do to make this work. I've tried connecting to a wifi using the terminal with both nmcli and wpa_supplicant and neither have worked. nmcli can't find the wifi and says that the wifi is "unmanaged".

Using wpa_supplicant I installed and added the network specifications to the config file and ran:

`sudo wpa_supplicant -B -i wlp1s0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf -D nl80211`

```
Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
```

But when running `sudo dhclient wlp1s0` nothing happened and `ps -e | grep wpa` gave:

```
  702 ?        00:00:00 wpa_supplicant
 6666 ?        00:00:25 wpa_supplicant
 6694 ?        00:00:25 wpa_supplicant
 6702 ?        00:00:24 wpa_supplicant
```

I am not experienced enough in Linux system and Ubuntu to know how to decode this. From what I can see I don't understand why I am not able to connect since the network card is both visible, the drivers are there, and it can find wifi's when scanning. I assume there is something I am missing or have done wrong. Any and all input is welcome and appreciated!