# Possible missing firmware (Xubuntu 18.04)

Tags: 18.04, xubuntu, firmware

I have received this warning for a few weeks when I upgrade certain packages such as kernel or firmware.

```
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8125a-3.fw for module r8169
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rtl8168fp-3.fw for module r8169
```

I wonder if I really need to install these firmware.

Xubuntu 18.04.5
Kernel 5.4.0-47
Onboard video card

I don't know exactly, it supposedly looks like a debian bug.
https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=947356

Thanks!

Comment: This is not a problem at all if your Ethernet works. I can explain why this message appears if you really want it.

Answer (score 0):

Login as root and execute these commands.

```
cd /lib/firmware/rtl_nic
wget https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/plain/rtl_nic/rtl8125a-3.fw
wget https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/plain/rtl_nic/rtl8168fp-3.fw
```

Comment: How about following up with a `sudo update-initramfs -u`?

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem as well, let's run the following commands altogether.

```
sudo apt-get update &&
sudo apt-get -y install make gcc linux-headers-$(uname -r) build-essential git &&
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw88.git &&
cd rtw88/ &&
make &&
sudo make install &&
sudo reboot
```

This will restart if the process is successful. Hopefully, after the restart, you will have the wifi back.

**When the kernel is changed**, you need to do the following:

```
cd ~/rtw88
git pull
make
sudo make install
```

This SHOULD be done whenever you have a new kernel - no exceptions.

***Reference:***

1. http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2018/08/no-wifi-adapter-found-hp-laptops-ubuntu-18-04/
2. https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw88

Comment: This is completely unrelated. Why would OP install Realtek wireless drivers? Did you read the question?

Comment: I downloaded the firmware on GitHub and put it in the folder indicated. I just don't know if it was necessary to do this.