# No Wi-Fi adapter found with Realtek 8822CE wireless LAN and Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS

Tags: 18.04, realtek-wireless

Realtek **8822CE** (NOT 8821CE) Wireless LAN 802.11ac PCI-E NIC
Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS with dual boot Windows 10
No Wi-Fi Adapter Found with Ubuntu

A Linux newbie so would prefer a simple fix. Tried fix with 8821CE solution, did not work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wifi adapter not found in ubuntu 18.04; no drivers for device rtl8822ce](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1216699/wifi-adapter-not-found-in-ubuntu-18-04-no-drivers-for-device-rtl8822ce)

Comment: Could not find string '0xC822' in /realtek/rtw88/pci.c to replace as suggested in solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have now solved my problem and have WiFi by upgrading to Ubuntu 20.4.1 with all additional options selected in the installation.