# Ubuntu 20.04 in Asus TUF Gaming FX505d - WIFI not working - Realtek RTL8822CE adapter - network UNCLAIMED

Tags: networking, drivers, 20.04, asus, realtek-wireless

community! This is my first question on the forum. I'm a new Ubuntu user and I would like some help with my Wifi adapter settings. It was working last week and now it's not, I don't know what happened.

I've recently followed [these](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/nvidia-xconfig-doesnt-do-what-i-want-it-to-nor-does-nvidia-settings/107883/7) instructions to enable a second monitor, but I think it shouldn't cause any trouble as those configs were made for graphical drivers.

Let's get into the details.
I am able to connect via ethernet but not via Wifi.

Kernel version: 5.8.0-43-generic

this is my lshw -C network output:

```
*-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: enp2s0
       version: 15
       serial: d4:5d:64:58:4f:09
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.8.0-43-generic duplex=full firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 ip=192.168.100.68 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:42 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:f7904000-f7904fff memory:f7900000-f7903fff

*-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: RTL8822CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:d000(size=256) memory:f7700000-f770ffff
```

I seem to have the correct driver installed, and also lsmod command shows it:

```
rtw_8822ce             16384  0
rtw_8822c             462848  1 rtw_8822ce
rtw_pci                24576  1 rtw_8822ce
rtw_core              188416  2 rtw_8822c,rtw_pci
mac80211              905216  2 rtw_core,rtw_pci
cfg80211              778240  3 wl,rtw_core,mac80211
```

Also, I don't find the module in etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf (not sure if this info is useful). There are more files on the folder, though.

I've tried to follow the solution in this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1216699/wifi-adapter-not-found-in-ubuntu-18-04-no-drivers-for-device-rtl8822ce/1228462#1228462) but could not find the string in the file mentioned, so I dropped the process.

Not sure if further information is required, but feel free to ask and I'll update the post.

Hope this helps others with the same issue :)

Thank you all very much in advance!

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you figure out the solution ?